# Put HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> in savedInstanceState

Tags: android, android-fragments, hashmap, android-savedstate

I have a problem with adding values in `savedInstanceState` in Android. I tried to find solution on the internet, but I cannot seem to find a solution. Maybe some of you might know where the problem is. I need to put HashMap> to `savedInstanceState`, and retrieve that onCreate method. Has anyone encountered and solved this problem?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use [putSerializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putSerializable(java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable)). E.g.

```
savedInstanceState.putSerializable("KEY", hashMapInstance);
```

Comment: and make sure your keys and values are serializable too.

Comment: Integer, List and HashMap implement serializable, @dit

Comment: op has no `MyCustomNoSerializableObject`. Op is using a `HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>` @dit

Comment: so I need to serialized keys and values, and this answers should work ?

Comment: which part is confusing you ?

Comment: I put my HashMap in savedInstanteState, and the problem is when I want to save that hashmap in other variable. I have variable `private HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> answers;` , and if my savedInstanceState is not empty, I want to put saved hash to answers. If I write `answers = savedInstanceState.getSerializable("KEY")`, it throws me error. Can you help me with saveing the saved state in new variable. Thank you

Comment: you have to cast the return value of `getSerializable` to the specific type: `answers = (HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("KEY");`. Including the specific error would be useful tough

Comment: Also User ArrayList. Other list classes do not serialize in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
private HashMap<String, String> savedInstanceMap = new HashMap<>();


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    savedInstanceMap.put("selectedFuel_type_Id", selectedFuel_type_Id);
    outState.putSerializable("savedBundle", savedInstanceMap);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

 @Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        savedInstanceMap = (HashMap<String, String>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("savedBundle");
        selectedFuel_type_Id = savedInstanceMap.get("selectedFuel_type_Id");
    }
```